# Подождать секунду

Tags: c++, время

Как можно в с++ без использования функции Sleep(1000) подождать одну секунду, а если конкретнее - эту секунду высчитать без заморозки интерфейса.

Comment: WaitForSingleObject в самый раз будет

Comment: В С++ нет встроенных средств для работы с интерфейсом, так что следует указать конкретную библиотеку / фреймворк, на котором пишется интерфейс.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно запускается (::CreateThread) один поток, в котором работает интерфейс и второй поток в котором идет отсчёт времени. Оба потока общаются друг с другом с помощью IPC (межпроцессного взаимодействия), например через сигналы или сообщения.

В рамках одного потока можно попробовать (в Windows) задержку через таймер сделать (::SetTimer) и отлавливать сообщения WM_TIMER

Answer (score -1):

[GetTickCount()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx), например, считает в миллисекундах. Запомнив первый раз считанное значение и сравнивая последующие считывания, можно определить, сколько прошло времени. 1000 миллисекунд даст 1 секунду.